# What is the semantic model of types?

Tags: reference-request, type-theory, semantics, denotational-semantics, types

By reading literature on (denotational) semantics of types, I see that people tried to give several models of types. Reynolds showed that types in general [cannot be given a set semantics in classical set theory](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076261/document). However, it was shown later that [constructive sets could be used](https://www.irif.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/articles/pitts-polymorphism-is-set-theoretic-constructively.pdf). Now, I also stumbled upon papers where types are seen as complete partial orders and [Scott domains](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2289&context=compsci). Further, Cardelli presents types as [ideals](http://lucacardelli.name/papers/onunderstanding.a4.pdf), but acknowledges that [retracts](http://agp.hx0.ru/arts/Scott.Datatypesaslattices.1975.pdf) should be used to handle parametric types.

I understand that one can give different models depending on the type system, but is there a known model of types that handles parametric types, universal parametric polymorphism, existential polymorphism, recursive types, and subtyping? For instance, where would I start if I want to give a denotational model for OCaml types (but without the side-effect features)?

Also, how does Reynolds' [relational model](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2010/course/DAT140_Types/Reynolds_typesabpara.pdf) relate (no pun intended) to the existing models?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Which kind of type system do you have in mind? The semantic models you mention are quite different and so it's hard to guess what sort of structure you want to model. If you're going to throw together a bunch of features you need to be far more specific: what sort of polymorphism? Whuch recursive types are allowed (in the presence of polymorphisms and subtyping)? What are the subtyping rules? It's easy to come up with something inconcsistent.

Comment: Fair point. I updated the answer to make it a bit more concrete. But, the vagueness of my question comes from the fact that I don't completely understand even why are there so many models and how do they relate. That is why I asked is there a single model (covering multiple features). My primary goal is to really understand what types denotationally mean.

Comment: Are you considering operational semantics as well, or just denotational? I'm not too familiar with denotational semantics, but operational semantics can give a clear definition of all these concepts.

Comment: I am not interested in the semantics of types induced by the typing rules. I am more interested in the semantic models as given in the work referenced above.

Comment: Operational semantics is not "induced by the typing rules" (in fact, semantic models *are* induced by the typing rule). Operational semantics is given with *even more rules* that specify an evaluation relation.

Comment: There are many models because type theory is not a single thing. There are many type theories, used for various purposes, and they are not all compatible with each other. There is no all-encompassing system and there is no single kind of model that would cover all other models.

Comment: @bellpeace I recommend to reflect on the meaning of "giving different models". Do you require your model to be precise, i.e. make exactly the same distinctions as the operational semantics, or only sound? If the former, you'll have a problem with conventional denotational semantics, since they are usually only sound, but not complete.

Comment: @AndrejBauer My impression was that particular semantics does not directly follow from the typing rules. In fact, Cardelli says "The rules are sound and can stand on their own, but have been discovered and justified by studying a particular semantics of types" in his seminal paper "On Understanding Types, Data Abstraction, and Polymorphism".

Comment: @MartinBerger Only sound is fine. "Different models" here means exactly as Andrej explained above. I am interested in models for type systems that one finds in practice, OCaml being the example I am interested in for now.

Comment: Sure, I should have said *constrainted* or *suggested* instead of *induced* in "semantic models are induced by the typing rules".

Comment: In my view, the problem is solved simply by considering an idealized computer as a virtual machine running your chosen version of lambda-calculus (with polymorphism, subtyping etc.) and with countably infinite memory. All programs must have finite size, and all data must have finite size, but they may be arbitrarily large. Then the set of all possible programs is a countably infinite set. So, any value computed by a program will belong to a countably infinite set of possible values. All types have some countably infinite set as a model. The set of all possible types is also countably infinite.